# close a slider after an intent is launched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, slider

I have an activity, DogActivity, with a slider. When the user slides view PawsView to a certain degree, I start another activity, CatActivity, using `startActivity(intent)`. If the user clicks the back button, normally the user returns to DogActivity. Here is my problem: if in `Developer options` I set `Do not keep activities` then when the user clicks the back button and thus returns to DogActivity, the slider is not asserted and so PawsView is back to its original position; however, if I don't have that option selected, upon returning to DogActivity the slider is still asserted (the sliding already occurred).

Since I don't want to depend on the user selecting or deselecting `Do not keep activities`, I need to do this programmatically. So does anyone know how to do this? I have tried putting the appropriate code inside onResume but that has no effect. It's as if finishing CatActivity has no effect on DogActivity. BTW, the view I am using to display PawsView is a custom view.

I already tried using a handler with postDelayed to pull PawsView back to normal, but the handler always executes before the startActivity is executed. If on the other hand I start a proper Thread to run the call to close the slider, I get an error about the wrong thread trying to change the layout.

Another way of asking the question may be: How do I force onResume to be called even when `Do not keep activities` is NOT selected on a user's device.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to launch CatActivity using `startActivityForResult` and then handle the result in `onActivityResult` and do the necessary setup from there. It's sort of like forcing `onResume`.

Comment: This is normally a good answer. But my design is as follows: The Activity has a ListView. The ListView has an Adapter. Inside the adapter I am laying out the views. One of the views is the custom view that slides to launch the intent. Unless I could somehow directly call onActivityResult from inside the custom view, this would be an error prone approach in my case.

Comment: Since you are sliding the list item, you could follow [Chet Haase's tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeuVuoa13S8&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_XOgcRukSoKKjewFJZrKV0&index=35) on Animating ListView deletion. If you look at the code, in the `ListViewItemAnimations Activity` he creates an `OnTouchListener` (use this on your custom listview item) which he passes to the `Adapter`. When you create the `OnTouchListener` I think you will have access to `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult`. It's just a matter of purposing the code.